# How to define a default typecast operator in C++

Tags: c++

I have overloaded typecast operator for few types. Now I want to call particular function for all the other typecastings. How can I do it?

Comment: `template <typename T>`

Comment: may I know the reason in voting to close the question?

Comment: yes, it was caused by a typo (`template<T>` should have been `template<typename T>`). Also, please don't edit the answer into the question

Answer (score 2):

Obvious but annoying problems.

1. Missing `typename` in `operator T()`.

   ```
   template <T>
   operator T();
   ```

   needs to be

   ```
   template <typename T>
   operator T();
   ```
2. Access problem.

   Either change `class Foo` to `struct Foo` or make the functions `public`.
3. Missing `;` at the end of the class definition.

The main problem is that you cannot specialize member function templates. However, you can overload them with equal effect.

```
struct Foo {
    template <typename T>
    operator T();

    operator int();

    operator char();
};
```